# Find all strings which has sub-string of an item in another string list

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have the following code.

```
let s1 = [(12, "abcde12345"); (23, "bcdef2345"); (12, "xyzafg3838")]
let s2 = ["bcd"; "345"]
```

What's the best way to find all items in `s1` which second item has sub-string of any one in `s2`?

> (12, "abcde12345"); (23, "bcdef2345")

In my real code s1 is a `Seq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out one.

```
s1 |> Seq.filter (fun i -> List.exists (fun e -> (snd i).Contains(e)) s2)
```

Comment: What is the point of doing `s1 |>` here? Why not `Seq.filter () s1`? And you can use pattern matching to avoid `snd` like `fun (_, x) -> ... x.Contains(e)...`.

Comment: And you can make it point-free `(x.Contains)` instead of `fun e -> x.Contains(e)`

Comment: The point free style is more understandable since there is less clutter, but I prefer the `|>` because it makes it more obvious that you're applying the result of passing a function to `Seq.filter` to `s1`.

Answer (score 3):

```ml
Seq.filter (fun (_, x) -> List.exists (x.Contains) s2) s1
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat all of the items from the second set into a regular expression, then apply it on each item in the first set.

```
open System
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let setA  = [ "One"; "Two"; "Three" ]
let setB = [ "o"; "n" ];

let pattern = String.Join("|", setB);
let regex = new Regex(pattern);

let results = setA |> List.filter (fun str -> regex.Match(str).Success)

results |> List.iter (fun result -> Console.WriteLine(result))
```